# Calculate the integral of a Pandas DataFrame column for specific time intervals (e.g. per day) using time index

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe (df) that includes power sensor data for a year. The data are sampled in irregular frequencies. My df is similar to that:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-07-30 12:00:00', periods=24, freq='6H')  
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6]), rng, columns=['power'])  
df.index.name = 'Date'
df["month"] = df.index.month
df["week"] = df.index.week
```

What I want to do is to calculate the integral for each day and then be able to sum up these integrals for different duration e.g. weekly, monthly, etc.

For the whole dataframe the following give correct answers (they consider the time in the x-axis):

```
np.trapz(df["power"], df.index, axis=0)/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
```

or

```
df.apply(integrate.trapz, args=(df.index,))/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
```

When I try to integrate per day I have tried:

```
df.groupby(df.index.date)["power"].apply(np.trapz)
```

It has two problems:

1. it assumes that the "power" measurements are equally spaced and are per 1 unit of time
2. it does not consider the contribution from the first time unit when the day changes (e.g. on 31/7/2020 the value should have been 13 but now it calculates 8.5

I also tried:

```
df.groupby(df.index.date)["power"].apply(integrate.trapz, args=(df.index,))
```

but I get: TypeError: trapz() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'

I would like my results to look like:

```
Date           Energy(kWh)
2020-07-30     15
2020-07-31     78
2020-08-01     84
2020-08-02     66
2020-08-03     78
2020-08-04     84
2020-08-05     30
```

and then to be able to groupby e.g.

```
df = df.groupby(["month", "week"])["power"].sum()
```

and the result looks like:

```
month  week    Energy(kWh)
7      31      93
8      31      150
       32      192
```

So how can I use in the integration, the index of my initial dataframe?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
dp = df.set_index('Date')
dp['Energy(kWh)'] = dp["power"].rolling('1D').apply(integrate.trapz) #1D is referenced as 1 day you can choose 1H or 1S.
```